# How is the same potential maintained in this case?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, capacitance, dielectric

suppose we take an isolated charged capacitor,,then put dielectric(k) in half the part,,,,now it behaves as two capacitors in parallel,,so potential difference must be same across them,,then the field must also be same in both of them,,,but there is a dielectric in one of them so charge density changes in the plate,,,now my question is ,,in a plate if there are places with different charge density how is equipotential condition maintained there(cuz the plate is a conductor) ,,,,,is there some sort of current in the plate?

Comment: a picture would greatly help.

Comment: i drew a diagram and clicked the photo but it says cant upload the image? donno whats the problem..

Comment: What makes you think the equipotential condition wont be exactly maintained by the differences in charges on each half of the plate perfectly matched to the differences in dielectric in the plate?

Comment: sir ,i have a little knowledge here,,i was just considering  the plate ,(a conductor) having different charge densities at different points ,i dont know how the dielectric between the plates would help to maintain equupotential in the plate.....sir it would be helpful if you could kindly explain a bit more..

Comment: Note that an [ellipses are constructed with *periods* (.), not *commas* (,)](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ellipses.html). It is also almost never actually needed in asking a question (only case is where you're quoting something and ignoring the unnecessary bits, but you're clearly not doing that here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constant surface charge density on the surface of a conductor is not a necessary condition for the conductor to be an equipotential.

[image]

The metal sphere on the right has induced charges on it.
The surface charge density is obviously not the same and yet the metal sphere is an equipotential volume.

In your example the induced charges on the dielectric are responsible for the redistribution of the charges on the plates of the capacitor so that the potential of each part of a plate is the same.